# Properly labeling multiple form fields with Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a simple login screen with a Username and Password input, I want to label each field so that if a user were to click on 'Username' or 'Password' it would automatically toggle the control to the field. Like the Facebook homepage does for example. My problem is that I don't know how I should properly use the `<input` tags:

```
<form action="/login/" method='post'>
    <label for='username_info'> Username </label>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.username }}
    <p>
    <label for="password_info"> Password </label>
    {{ form.password }}
    <p>
    <input id='username_info' type='submit'>
</form>
```

So that works for the `Username` text but not for the `Password` text obviously. How do I properly label each field? I looked at the [Django Docs example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#building-a-form) but when I try to use a django template tag as the `value` attribute for the `input` tag it only displays the raw html in the field.

edit: forms.py file:

from django import forms
from models import LoginInfo

```
class LoginForms(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = LoginInfo
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't use labels in the landing form, they use placeholders. This is how you use one with django forms:

```
q = forms.CharField(label='username', 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
```

For more info look at the [widgets documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/).

**Edit:** Answering your question in the comment, your **forms.py** will look somewhat like this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

> Would this effect my models at all?

No, it wouldn't even if you save it, because it's not linked to any model.

Comment: thanks for this, I just have a question. I was reading the docs, how would I implement this into my forms.py file? Would this effect my models at all?

Comment: Okay thanks, right now I'm using a `Meta` class that links to my models, that's why I ask the question. I am currently creating my forms from models like it says in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: So I'm not sure how I should change my forms.py file if the forms are being made from models

Comment: Find some info in the docs about it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: @Amon, you can use a simple form, not a modelform one, because in login function you don't have to validate anything, you do that at registration. [See these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in). All you need to do is to get username and password, whatever they are, and pass them to the _authenticate_ function.

Comment: So I don't need models at all for this?

Comment: @Amon, Yes, I think you don't.

Comment: Okay, yea I'm already using Django's authenticate feature. I just assumed we needed to make the form from a model, I think I assumed that because the website I learned from was making a blog post website. But I still seem to be having the same issue, where I can't click on the text and toggle the control so it selects the field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the problem here. But you can give labels in your **forms.py** like this:

```
username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length = 100)
password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length = 100)
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Hey the problem is that I want to properly use the <label> tag instead. That way if someone clicks on the text "username" it will highlight the field. Go to Facebook.com for example and try it. Right now my code works but only for the "Username" field

Answer (score 1):

Use the `label_tag` attribute, which will automatically output the HTML for the label.

```
<p>
{{ form.password.label_tag }}
{{ form.password }}
</p>
```